# name "change" is not defined kivy

Tags: python, kivy

so basically what this code should do is have a button that, when clicked, changes the variable z, which = 0.5, to z - 0.5.

```
 def change(self, obj):
        z = z - 0.1
        return z

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        x = randint(1,10)
        print (x)
        y = 'water.png'
        if x==1:
            y = 'a.png'
        if x==2:
            y = 'b.png'
        if x==3:
            y = 'c.png'
        if x==4:
            y = 'd.png'
        if x==5:
            y = 'e.png'
        if x==6:
            y = 'f.png'
        if x==7:
            y = 'g.png'
        if x==8:
            y = 'h.png'
        if x==9:
            y = 'i.png'
        if x==10:
            y = 'j.png'
        z = 0.5
        super(MyBackground, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            btnworking = Button(text = "opacity50%")
            btnworking.bind(on_press=change)
            self.add_widget(btnworking)
            Color(1, 1, 1, 0.5)
            self.bg = Rectangle(source=y, pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        self.bind(pos=self.update_bg)
        self.bind(size=self.update_bg)

    def update_bg(self, *args):
        self.bg.pos = self.pos
        self.bg.size = self.size
```

it says the name change isnt defined when i call it on the button

Comment: `btnworking.bind(on_press=` **`self.`** `change)`

Comment: And while you're here, those ifs can be collapsed to `y = 'abcdefghij'[x-1] + '.png'`